# Bootstrap - How to Make Rows Have No Padding?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap seems to want to enforce its own padding everywhere within the grid system (I'm using the non-responsive "container", "row", and "span.." classes.)  I'd prefer to make my own widgets that live inside the constraints of the row system but enforce their own padding.  Is there a canonical way to control the padding behavior of Bootstrap's rows?

Comment: `padding:0px` isn't doing the job?

Comment: Things seem to get wonky when I try to override Bootstrap styles.  I'll try to quantify that better, though . . .

Comment: What happens if you apply `!important` to the relevant properties?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can customize padding values in LESS variables and re-compile. http://twbs.github.io/bootstrap/customize/

Comment: Haven't touched webdev for a while but, this is the first place I'd go fishing.